# Friendly_id Unique contraint with scope and history

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

```
'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
```

I'm trying to add 'scoped' to my existing slugs.

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord   
  extend FriendlyId   
  belongs_to :board   
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :scoped, :history], :scope => :board
```

But I'm coming up with this error when a duplicate is run that should have a different scope.

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate
>   key value violates unique constraint "index_models_on_slug" DETAIL: 
>   Key (slug)=(xxx-xxxx-xxx) already exists.

Looking through the logs, I can see the scope is generating and lists the scope model (via board_id, xx), which I assume is as it should, but it doesn't seem to be searching the scope when saving.

If I create a duplicate under that same scope, it adds the duplicate code ("42a8d035-ba2f-4a51-b85e-0872c4e207e2").

I hope this makes sense - Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I should have thought about this post a bit more.

[“Key (slug)=() already exists” in friendly_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882054/key-slug-already-exists-in-friendly-id-on-rails4-app)

Adding the scope on existing models meant I didn't think about but had to remove the unique=true on the existing model.

Anyway - love friendly_id great product!

Comment: you should only modify the unique on both columns : `add_index(:table_name, %i[scoped_column slug], unique: true)`; keeping unicity at the database level is preferrable